# Print array of numbers in Javascript in this order (first-last, second-last second....)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

> Write a "PrintZigZag" program that provides an array of 10 integers
> containing any values and prints the elements in the following order:
> the first-the last, the second-the last second, etc ... (The program
> must be written pretending not to know what the values entered in the
> array are)

This was a interview question for a position of "Junior Web Developer" and i didn't know how to solve it...

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Comment: what does not work? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the ZigZag pattern. "the first-the last, the second-the last second" If you meant the first position is now the last and the second to last number is the second. Wouldn't that be equivalent to just reversing the array?

Comment: @S.Ramjit He wants to print `1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, ...`

Answer (score 2):

this is the result you're looking for?

`[1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6]`

I really enjoy interview questions, thankyou for sharing. please let me help explain what im doing here

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var result = [];
for(i=1; i< numbers.length+1 /2; i++) {
    result.push(i);
    result.push(numbers.pop());

}
```

I am looping over half the array starting at 1. Then I am pushing the first index onto the result array, and then straight after I am popping off the last number of the array.

This will build up a new array consisting of the first number and then the last number, eventually reaching the end.

Comment: I could do this with a Mapping function, but in this case, its a junior developer looking to learn so I kept it basic

Comment: you push i instead of the real number indexed value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  @SweetChillyPhilly. 
Well, i didn't really know the rules of stackoverflow for posting a question. This is my first time posting something here, as you can see, i created the account today.
I apologize for any inconvenience. Have a nice evening

Comment: You're absolutely fine man, im just trying to help you

Comment: @Cosmin Dumi Welcome! Some people here are very helpful and others less so. As mentioned, the typical etiquette is to post the code that you've tried already and we'll help you find a solution, but no worries. Good luck in the interviews.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Sweet Chilly Philly's solution using .map. An interviewer will probably want to see you use the for loop, but knowing modern loops could help as well.

```
let arr = [];
numbers.map(item => {
   arr.push(item);
   arr.push(numbers[numbers.length - 1])
   numbers.pop()
})
```

And here's a solution with a do, while loop as Peter S mentioned. Be careful with these since they can end in an infinite loop if not escaped correctly.

```
let arr = [];
do {
  arr.push(numbers[0])
  arr.push(numbers[numbers.length - 1])
  numbers.shift()
  numbers.pop()
} while (numbers.length > 0)
```

Comment: One actually never wants to misuse `map` like in the example shown above ... and the `while` based approach might look more similar to this one ... `while (numbers.length) { result = result.concat(numbers.shift(), numbers.pop()); }` ... and of course the latter approach does mutate the original array which will be empty after the `while` has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Peter! Yours is a nice solution.